# Generating constructor documentation for class defined in C++

Tags: python

When developing a Python plug-in (in C++), how does one go about setting
the documentation for `__new__`?  In particular, given a new type
defined by a `PyTypeObject` structure in the C++, how does one document
the arguments which can be passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor arguments are usually documented in the type docstring, i.e. via the `tp_doc` slot, so you can do `help(type)` (or `type?` in IPython) instead of `help(type.__new__)` or `help(type.__init__)`.

Comment: If you do `help(mytype)`, Python displays `__new__` automatically, but with its documentation, which doesn't document the parameters.  That's what I want to replace.